# Send whatsapp audio file programmatically

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing a game app and I want to send an audio file to my specified contacts. Is there any way to do it without user intervention?

I was thinking about whatsapp to send the audio file, but all I found asks to the user to send the info. I want the app doing it without asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simple answer is **No** you can't.

WhatsApp have not provided any public API or SDK.

So only you can launch intent but you can't send it without user intervention.